# I want to create a back button in a tkinter program to recreate a filled form. How do I reopen a withdrawn root window?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, root

Is there a way I can reopen a withdrawn window? I know it is impossible with the destroy function, but I would imagine it would be possible to do so after using the the withdraw function.

I created a root1 loop and a root2 loop which opens after the root1 is closed. I have a back button on the second window, and I am trying to figure out a command which will reopen the first window with a entry field still filled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way I can reopen a withdrawn window?

You do that by calling the `deiconify` method.

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
...
root.deiconify()
```

Comment: This worked for me, thank you! I have been looking all over for a command that would reopen the window and kept coming up short.